# HTML 5 Using canvas in flexbox causes weird scaling

Tags: html, css, canvas, flexbox

When using canvas in a flexbox and drawing rects of the same size it appears to be glitching.

Take a look at the following example:
It draws a one by one pixel rect to your cursor location but the drawn rectangles are of different size relative to the distance of the top left corner.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let x = event.offsetX;
  let y = event.offsetY;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, x + 1, y + 1);
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#first {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: green;
  width: 60px;
}

#second {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
  
}

canvas {
  
  object-fit:none;
  object-position:top left;
}

#third {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: green;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="160px"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't see anything weird, you are defining the width/height using the cursor position so they will not be the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect. The third and fourth arguments for fillRect are the height and width, not positions. So if I understand correctly, you would want these both to just be 1 if you are looking for a 1x1 square.

Comment: Omg thank you! This damn inconsistency across languages annoys me.
I searched for the problem at every position but the most obvious one.